# How to add custom HardConstraint in VRP for optaplanner?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

Thanks optaplanner team for such a fantastic Project.

I need to add a constraint in Vehicle called capacityCap (a customer is assigned to the vehicle only if the "demand <= capacityCap")
I have added a variable capacityCap in **Vehicle.java**.

```
protected int capacityCap;
public int getCapacityCap() {
    return capacityCap;
}

public void setCapacityCap(int capacityCap) {
    this.capacityCap = capacityCap;
}
```

And added drool for this in **vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl**

```
// Hard constraints
rule "vehicleCapacityCap"
when
    $vehicle : Vehicle($capacityCap : capacityCap)
    $customer : Customer(demand > $capacityCap);
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

But after running it leaves all the customer unassigned.Am I doing some wrong in drool ?

**UseCase for This:**
If I want to assign order to a **biker** only if it weights less than 5Kg.

Please ask if more information needed.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
// Hard constraints
rule "vehicleCapacityCap"
when
   $vehicle : Vehicle($capacityCap : capacityCap)
   $customer : Customer(vehicle == $vehicle, demand > $capacityCap);
then
   scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

Comment: Still it is leaving the order (customer) unassigned.

Comment: How do you achive that customer can be unassigned (I am not telling that this is wrong). I was thinking that in chained planning all entities must be initialized in construction phase.

Comment: Sorry, It was my wrong, the drool you given absolutely worked fine.I was initialising the capacityCap wrongly.

Comment: Mateusz , why we needed "vehicle == $vehicle" ? can you please explain ?
thank you.

Comment: This specific $vehicle has $capacityCap and you want to check that demand > $capacityCap only in this customers where this specific $vehicle is assinged to. Without vehicle == $vehicle, u can check demand > $capacityCap but $capacityCap can be from other vehicle.

VehicleA(capacityCapA = 5)
VehicleB(capacityCapB = 10)

VehicleA -> Customer1 -> Customer2 -> Customer3;
VehicleB -> Customer11 -> Customer12 -> Customer13;
Without vehicle == $vehicle drool can be fire for Customer11 where 
demand > $capacityCap => deman > 5 but should be deman > 10